# When adding background padding to a link, it moves other links so how do i fix?

Tags: html, css

Making a website and having a problem where when i hover over a link the other links around it move

Instead of using `li` tags to surround the drop down menus, i used `div` instead and that didnt work, i tried css `box-sizing: border-box` and even `clear:both` those did nothing as well.

```css
:root {
  --primary-color: #00ccd8;
  --secondary-color: #2679af;
  --tertiary-color: #323232;
  --background-color: #FFFFFF;
  --nav-color: #cccccc;
  --main-text-color: #000000;
  --secondary-text-color: #FFFFFF;
  --links-background-color: #303030;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font: 16px/1.5 'Roboto', 'Rubik', sans-serif;
  background-color: var(--background-color);
}


/* Global */

.container {
  width: 75%;
  margin: auto;
}


/* Header */

header {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

header .top-bar {
  height: 3.5vh;
  background-color: var(--primary-color);
}

header .logo {
  width: 100%;
}

header .logo img {
  height: 15vh;
}

header nav {
  position: relative;
  background-color: var(--nav-color);
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

header nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 20px 30px;
}

header nav ul li a {
  color: var(--main-text-color);
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
}

header nav ul li a:hover {
  background-color: var(--links-background-color);
  color: var(--secondary-text-color);
  padding: 5px 7px;
  border-radius: 25px;
}

header nav ul li ul li {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<header>

  <div class="top-bar"></div>

  <div class="logo">
    <img src="Pictures/Logo.jpg" alt="Logo">
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <nav>
      <ul>

        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>

        <li><a href="#">About CADA</a>
          <ul>

            <li><a href="#">Overview</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Staff</a></li>

          </ul>
        </li>

        <li><a href="#">Memberships</a>
          <ul>

            <li><a href="#">Members</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Membersip Applications</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Medical Device Establishment License</a></li>

          </ul>
        </li>

        <li><a href="#">Reports</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">News & Publications</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Board of Directors</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>

      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>

</header>
```

When hovering over the links all other surrounding links should not move

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now you have

`header nav ul li a:hover {
 padding: 5px 7px;
}`

You should move your padding rule out of the hover selector and into `header nav ul li`, so your code should now be:

```
header nav ul li a {
    color: var(--main-text-color);
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 5px 7px;
}

header nav ul li a:hover {
    background-color: var(--links-background-color);
    color: var(--secondary-text-color);
    border-radius: 25px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of increasing padding on `hover`, you add it to the `a` tag by default. See code below.

```css
:root {
  --primary-color: #00ccd8;
  --secondary-color: #2679af;
  --tertiary-color: #323232;
  --background-color: #FFFFFF;
  --nav-color: #cccccc;
  --main-text-color: #000000;
  --secondary-text-color: #FFFFFF;
  --links-background-color: #303030;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font: 16px/1.5 'Roboto', 'Rubik', sans-serif;
  background-color: var(--background-color);
}


/* Global */

.container {
  width: 75%;
  margin: auto;
}


/* Header */

header {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

header .top-bar {
  height: 3.5vh;
  background-color: var(--primary-color);
}

header .logo {
  width: 100%;
}

header .logo img {
  height: 15vh;
}

header nav {
  position: relative;
  background-color: var(--nav-color);
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

header nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 20px 30px;
}

header nav ul li a {
  color: var(--main-text-color);
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 5px 7px;
}

header nav ul li a:hover {
  background-color: var(--links-background-color);
  color: var(--secondary-text-color);
  
  border-radius: 25px;
}

header nav ul li ul li {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="top-bar"></div>
  <div class="logo">
    <img src="Pictures/Logo.jpg" alt="Logo">
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About CADA</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Overview</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Staff</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Memberships</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Members</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Membersip Applications</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Medical Device Establishment License</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Reports</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">News & Publications</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Board of Directors</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this css:

```
        :root {
    --primary-color: #00ccd8;
    --secondary-color: #2679af;
    --tertiary-color: #323232;
    --background-color: #FFFFFF;
    --nav-color: #cccccc;
    --main-text-color: #000000;
    --secondary-text-color: #FFFFFF;
    --links-background-color: #303030;
}

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    font: 16px/1.5 'Roboto', 'Rubik', sans-serif;
    background-color: var(--background-color);
}

/* Global */
.container {
    width: 75%;
    margin: auto;
}

/* Header */
header {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

header .top-bar {
    height: 3.5vh;
    background-color: var(--primary-color);
}

header .logo {
    width: 100%;
}

header .logo img {
height: 15vh;
}

header nav {
    position: relative;
    background-color: var(--nav-color);
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

header nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 20px 30px;
}

header nav ul li a {
    color: var(--main-text-color);
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 5px 7px
}

header nav ul li a:hover {
    background-color: var(--links-background-color);
    color: var(--secondary-text-color);
    padding: 5px 7px;
    border-radius: 25px;
}

header nav ul li ul li {
    display: none;
}
```